# "auseinander", "zueinander", "miteinander", "nebeneinander" and other "preposition + einander" versions

Tags: usage, adverb

I'm always confused how to use these words. I'm wondering in which context they have usage. Are these expressions possible?

> Du lebst in den USA, aber ich lebe in Deutschland, also sind wir auseinander.
>
> Wir müssen nebeneinander laufen.
>
> Sie passen zueinander.
>
> Sie diskutieren immer noch miteinander.

And please, can someone explain the usage of others?

durcheinander,ohneeinander,voneinander etc.

Comment: Read "-einander" as "each other" and everything should be clearer. Sorry, had to VTC.

Answer (score 1):

First, an answer about the possibility of the expressions:

The first one seems strange, the others are totally normal usage of the words. The reason why the first one seems strange is that "auseinander" is normally used in a processual description of a movement of two things that normally belonged to each other:

> Sie haben sich auseinandergelebt.
>
> Die Kontinente driften auseinander.

The "-einander"-words in general adverbials that endorse a reciproc structure of the actions of two seperate instances:

> Wir müssen nebeneinander laufen.

The walking is described in a manner which has to be understood as a normative aspect: The action is attributed by "nebeneinander" so that the correct execution of the action includes a reciprocical bindingness. One cannot perform it for herself.

Comment: when i say "wir leben uns auseinander" would it be a correct experession, i mean "auseinander" requires a reciprocal(gegenseitig) action?

Comment: @Bergmann: When two people move in different directions, each of them increases the distance to the other.